# javassist get CtClass from a third party library/jar

Tags: java, javassist

I want to add with javassist a SLF4J logger in my class. So first, I try to get its CtClass such as I can build the field after:

```
CtClass loggerClass = pool.get(org.slf4j.Logger.class.getName());
```

But I never pass that line and always get a javassist.NotFoundException.

I tried different things:

```
pool.importPackage("org.slf4j.Logger");
// or
pool.importPackage("org.slf4j");
```

And I even tried to pass org.slf4j.Logger to the URLClassLoader:

```
// add org.slf4j.Logger to the list of urls...
// then:
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ClassPool.getDefault().insertClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(loader));
```

But nothing works.

Note: This is how *pool* is created just after the call to insertClassPath:

```
final ClassPool pool = new ClassPool(ClassPool.getDefault());
pool.childFirstLookup = true;
```

I'm completely stuck here.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide the path upto the jar file name. 
 Check below code. I coud able to see the Logger class loaded of slf4j

```
ClassPool pool = new ClassPool(ClassPool.getDefault());
pool.appendClassPath("./otherlib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar");
CtClass ctClass = pool.get("org.slf4j.Logger");
System.out.println(ctClass);
```

Comment: Funny. I found the solution a few minutes after you replied [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745206/javassist-using-a-jar-file]
That's it indeed. Thanks. :)

Comment: Actually I found the answer one hour before but it was lunch time :P